# WSO2 API Manager and IS as Keymanager: User not authorized for Application

Tags: caching, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've set up the API Manager and the IS as Key Manager. (2.1.0 and 5.3.0)
Furthermore I've set up a Primary and a Secondary Userstore.

We've created Users in the Secondary Userstore and used them to subscribe to Applications succesfully in the past, but suddenly, that does not work anymore.

When creating an application to subscribe APIs to and then generating the access tokens the AM and IS throw errors.

**IS:**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-17 09:07:37,479]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationManagementServiceImpl} -  Illegal Access! User EXTERNAL/test@test.com does not have access to the application EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710170906_SANDBOX
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-17 09:07:37,480] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil} -  Error occurred while creating ServiceProvider for app EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710170906_SANDBOX
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.IdentityApplicationManagementException: Error occurred while updating the application: EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710170906_SANDBOX
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.updateApplication(ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.java:300)
[...]
Caused by:  org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.IdentityApplicationManagementException: User not authorized
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.updateApplication(ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.java:277)
```

**AM:**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-17 09:07:37,490] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl} -  Can not create OAuth application  : 201710170906_SANDBOX {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl} 
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException
[...]
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-17 09:07:37,492] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil} -  Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient. {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : 201710170906_SANDBOX
[...]
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor339.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

I've tried and tested a couple things and verified in the database (Oracle) directly:

- When I create an application it is created in the database. (key store)
- When I subscribe to an api, the link between api and app is created in the database.
- When I generate the access tokens the errors occur, the role for the user is created. (auth store)

  - "View Users" on the role shows the users having the role.
  - "View Roles" on the user does not show the user having the role.
  - SP_APP table in the database contains the newly created application, but without an access token.
- When I delete the application

  - the SP_APP stays in the database.
  - the Role stays in the database.

But now for the tricky part:
Everything works fine for users in the Primary Userstore.

And the really tricky part:
Sometimes (like once every 15-20 times), the token generation for Secondary Users works.

**[EDIT]**

Further investigation lead me to the assumption, that something is wrong with the user/role caching/reading.

**Logs from the key manager:**

Questions:

- Why does the `org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet` throw an NPE?
- Shouldn't the `2017-10-18 19:46:28,877` part work after it created the roles in the DB without a problem?

The full log:

```
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,732] DEBUG -  Created singleton instance for org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager {org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,733] DEBUG -  Get first priority handler for the given handler list. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,733] DEBUG -  Get first priority handler : DefaultAuthenticationManager(org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.AuthenticationManager) {org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,733] DEBUG -   {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.createMessageContext(AxisServlet.java:715)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.createMessageContext(AxisServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:138)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  getAction (null) from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@72ca18ef {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  Old SoapAction is (null) {org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  New SoapAction is (null) {org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  setAction Old action is (null) {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  setAction New action is (null) {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  Input contentType (application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action="urn:createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo") {org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  CharSetEncoding from content-type (UTF-8) {org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  getAction (null) from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@72ca18ef {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  Old SoapAction is (null) {org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  New SoapAction is (urn:createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo) {org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  setAction Old action is (null) {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  setAction New action is (urn:createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo) {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  getAction (urn:createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo) from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@72ca18ef {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  SoapAction is (urn:createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo) {org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  createSOAPEnvelope using Builder (class org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder) selected from type (application/soap+xml) {org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  char set encoding set from default =UTF-8 {org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,734] DEBUG -  [MessageContext: logID=62aa565ba9f5ad1bb8a9618af3ccb60006e855dbc7d5825a] Checking for Service using target endpoint address : https://wimtest.domain.com/services/APIKeyMgtSubscriberService {org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedServiceDispatcher}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  org.apache.axis2.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(servicefound) {org.apache.axis2.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  [MessageContext: logID=62aa565ba9f5ad1bb8a9618af3ccb60006e855dbc7d5825a] Found AxisService : APIKeyMgtSubscriberService {org.apache.axis2.engine.AbstractDispatcher}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  getAction (urn:createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo) from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@72ca18ef {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  SoapAction is (urn:createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo) {org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  [MessageContext: logID=62aa565ba9f5ad1bb8a9618af3ccb60006e855dbc7d5825a] Checking for Operation using Action : urn:createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo {org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.ActionBasedOperationDispatcher}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  getOperationBySOAPAction: Operation (org.apache.axis2.description.InOutAxisOperation@5dd7070f,createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo) for soapAction: urn:createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo found in action map. {org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  org.apache.axis2.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(operationfound) {org.apache.axis2.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  [MessageContext: logID=62aa565ba9f5ad1bb8a9618af3ccb60006e855dbc7d5825a] Found AxisOperation : createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo {org.apache.axis2.engine.AbstractDispatcher}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  getAddressingRequirementParemeterValue: value: 'null' {org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingHelper}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  [MessageContext: logID=62aa565ba9f5ad1bb8a9618af3ccb60006e855dbc7d5825a] isReplyRedirected: ReplyTo is null. Returning false {org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingHelper}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  Resolving tenant id from tenant domain {org.wso2.carbon.context.PrivilegedCarbonContext}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  Authorization cache miss for username : admin resource /permission/admin/login action : ui.execute {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,735] DEBUG -  Roles which have permission for resource : /permission/admin/login action : ui.execute {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,736] DEBUG -  Role :  admin {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,736] DEBUG -  Role :  INTERNAL/creator {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,736] DEBUG -  Role :  INTERNAL/subscriber {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,736] DEBUG -  Role :  INTERNAL/publisher {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,736] DEBUG -  Retrieving internal roles for user name :  admin and search filter * {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,740] DEBUG -  Searching for user admin {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,740] DEBUG -  Replace escape characters configured to: true {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,740] DEBUG -  Replace escape characters configured to: true {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,740] DEBUG -  value after escaping special characters in admin : admin {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,740] DEBUG -  User: admin exist: true {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,740] DEBUG -  Replace escape characters configured to: true {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,740] DEBUG -  Reading roles with the memberOfProperty Property: memberOf {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,740] DEBUG -  Result for searchBase: CN=admin,OU=EDV,DC=test,DC=com searchFilter: (&(|(objectClass=userProxyFull)(objectClass=user))(mail=admin)) property:memberOf appendDN: false {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,755] DEBUG -  Replace escape characters configured to: true {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,757] DEBUG -  Found user: CN=admin,OU=GROUPS,DC=test,DC=com {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,757] DEBUG -  Result  :  CN=admin,OU=GROUPS,DC=test,DC=com {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,757] DEBUG -  GetGroupNameAttributeValuesOfGroups with DN {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,773] DEBUG -  Using DN: CN=admin,OU=GROUPS,DC=test,DC=com {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,773] DEBUG -  Found role: admin {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,774] DEBUG -  admin user has permitted resource :  /permission/admin/login, action :ui.execute {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,774] DEBUG -  getAction (null) from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@7889e70c {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,774] DEBUG -  Old WSAAction is (null) {org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,774] DEBUG -  New WSAAction is (urn:createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfoResponse) {org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,774] DEBUG -  setAction Old action is (null) {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,774] DEBUG -  setAction New action is (urn:createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfoResponse) {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,774] DEBUG -  messageID is null. {org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,778] DEBUG -  Resolving tenant id from tenant domain {org.wso2.carbon.context.PrivilegedCarbonContext}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,778] DEBUG -  Creating application role : Application/EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX and assign the user : [EXTERNAL/test@test.com] to that role {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationMgtUtil}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,779] DEBUG -  Is roleName: Application/EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX Exist: false TenantId: -1234 {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,783] DEBUG -  Is roleName: Application/EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX Exist: false TenantId: -1234 {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,792] DEBUG -  Executed a batch update. Query is : INSERT INTO UM_HYBRID_USER_ROLE (UM_USER_NAME, UM_ROLE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID, UM_DOMAIN_ID) VALUES (?,(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_HYBRID_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), ?, (SELECT UM_DOMAIN_ID FROM UM_DOMAIN WHERE UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_DOMAIN_NAME=?)): and result is[1] {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,812] DEBUG -  Creating Application EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX for user EXTERNAL/test@test.com {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,820] DEBUG -  Application Stored successfully with application id 135 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,822] DEBUG -  Loading Basic Application Data of EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,823] DEBUG -  ApplicationID: 135 ApplicationName: EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX UserName: test@test.com TenantDomain: carbon.super {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,823] DEBUG -  Reading Clients of Application 135 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,825] DEBUG -  Reading Steps of Application 135 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,831] DEBUG -  Reading Claim Mappings of Application 135 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,834] DEBUG -  Reading Role Mapping of Application 135 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,874] DEBUG -  Clearing cache entry for EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning.listener.ProvisioningApplicationMgtListener}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,874] DEBUG -  Provisioning cached entry not found for sp EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning.listener.ProvisioningApplicationMgtListener}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,874] DEBUG -  Checking whether user has role : Application/EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX by retrieving role list of user : EXTERNAL/test@test.com {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationMgtUtil}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,874] DEBUG -  Loading Application Name for ID: 135 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,876] DEBUG -  ApplicationName : EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,877] DEBUG -  Checking whether user has role : Application/EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX by retrieving role list of user : EXTERNAL/test@test.com {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationMgtUtil}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,877]  WARN -  Illegal Access! User EXTERNAL/test@test.com does not have access to the application EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationManagementServiceImpl}
[2017-10-18 19:46:28,877] ERROR -  Error occurred while creating ServiceProvider for app EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil}
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.IdentityApplicationManagementException: Error occurred while updating the application: EXTERNAL_test-AT-test.com_201710181946_SANDBOX
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.updateApplication(ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.java:300)
```

Regards,
Mat

Answer (score 1):

so, I found a fix to the current problem.

The caching configuration for the roles in the secondary userstore was somehow not working correctly. The UI configuration did not disable the cache, but showed it disabled. After I changed the configuration in the xml, it did disable the role caching and the problem is gone. (Now the UI works to en- and disable the cache).

However, as soon as I reactivate the caching, the problem is back again (still with a random small chance of running smoothly through the workflow).

The caching is on for the development and live environment, and we do not have problems there. So somehow, the test environment doesn't want to clear the cache/reload the data for the user roles... Strange...

So it is not ideal, but at least usable again. But if someone has a clue how to fix the caching issue, I would be glad to know!

Cheers,
Mat